# Can i apply for a schengen visa in UAE if i am having a tourist visa in UAE

Tags: visas, international-travel

I am an Indian Citizen, studying in Hong Kong and hence have a Student Visa in Hong Kong. 
My Parents are in Dubai UAE and have a resident visa of UAE, and are planning a trip to Europe. My plan is to go to Dubai on a Tourist Visa and from there all of us travel together. Can i apply for the schengen visa when i am in Dubai on a tourist visa?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. You should apply at the consulate responsible for your *place of residence* which is probably the one for Hong Kong.

You can try and ask for an exception, but that's not a good way to start an application.